# Is it possible to bypass escape() when document.getElementByName gets the value?

Tags: xss, javascript

Say I have the following script

```
var a = document.getElementById('in').value;
escape(a);
```

Is it possible to bypass the escape function to do some XSS? I have tried `);alert(1);` to no avail. I have tried `");alert(1);` but that doesn't work either. I'm guessing its because `document.getElementById` returns a string. Anyway to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to bypass the escape function to do some XSS?**
May be yes, if you can control sink and source of data, then DOM based XSS is possible.

In your case, Escape function does the trick here, escape() function's 1st step is another function **ToString()**; whose job is to convert all input to string, then escape() goes on to calculate the number of characters that needs change and at last replace it. You can bypass it if you are able to add unescape() function at the sink. unescape will undo the escape function and no more encoding is presented at last which **may trigger XSS hopefully**.

**");alert(1);** will not work because this is encoded by the escape function. the only characters exempted are

@*_+-./

For your information, below is what escape function simple algorithm looks like straight from [ECMA262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-escape-string):